# How do you make a "user tutorial"? - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

**How do you create a viewcontroller, in which can be programmed to be a "user tutorial", which appears at startup (when the app is first introduced to the user) and disappears after the user taps a button to either skip or complete the tutorial?**

Here is an example screenshot of what I'm aiming for:

[image]

Further details:

I am capable of creating the pageviewcontroller on a view controller, the main question points towards creating a system in which the viewcontroller disappears with a button and appears at startup when the app is **first introduced** to the user.

Comment: I have refactored the question. I also would appreciate it if the question would open up for others to input on their strategies.

Comment: Have a look at this library, it seems to be what you want https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough.

Comment: @user1135437 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this in the following sample project that I have developed for you, it is fully documented for your understanding and uploaded it [over here.](https://mega.co.nz/#!xB4GHCxD!8ukLEQQSsZ9adFs64vLlNgLuGjyfdMeHfQCvflKW-Vc)

How does it work. UIViewController, which is the First View Controller (This will be the first viewcontroller of your app) has a variable called "value" of type Int which by default is set to "0", when the View appears it will see that value is equal to cero so it will perform the segue TutorialSegue which will take you to the "Tutorial" View. Tutorial View has a button which will turn the value of "value" to 1. Making the Main View Appear.

(Sorry for answering your question on an xcode project, I couldn't find a better way to explain)

Comment: I can see your strategy there, thank you so much for helping me. I am quite new to delegates, and I'm glad you used one. I'm starting to understand how to use them better. This is such a great strategy. Ok, I noticed also that the tutorial comes back. So I'm guess I should use "persistent Storage" to verify the value. Where do you recommend I set the persistent Storage to check this? Would it be in the App Delegate? If so, where exactly?

Comment: And no need to be sorry, your project is so helpful! Thank you so much, you saved me there. Especially now that the question is on hold (thankfully you answered before those guys did the hold).

Comment: One option that you have is using Core Data for storing the value of the variable. Here is a helpful link about Core Data: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/